# Restrict update method to only modify request user's own data?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have an Update method in DRF to allow users to update their own profile. The api endpoint is `PUT /api/users/{id}/` where id is his own user id. If he attempts to update any other users profile he will receive a HTTP403.

The way I am doing it right now is

```
def update(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    """
    Update user profile
    """
    if int(kwargs['id']) is not request.user.id:
        return Response({}, status=status.HTTP_403_FORBIDDEN)
    return super(UserViewSet, self).update(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

I am hoping to do this in a more elegant way, perhaps with a decorator or something?

Comment: Are you using token authentications?

Comment: Yes I am using Token Authentication

Answer (score 4):

You can create a `CustomUpdatePermission` class which will grant access to update requests depending on whether the `id` in the url and `request.user.id` matched or not.

We will check first check that its an `update` request. If it was, we will check the value of `id` in the url with the `id` of `request.user`. If they did not match, request will not be granted access and a `403 Forbidden` response will be returned.

```
from rest_framework import permissions

class CustomUpdatePermission(permissions.BasePermission):
    """
    Permission class to check that a user can update his own resource only
    """

    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        # check that its an update request and user is modifying his resource only
        if view.action == 'update' and view.kwargs['id']!=request.user.id:
            return False # not grant access
        return True # grant access otherwise
```

You can include this permission class in your `UserViewset` by defining `permission_classes` setting.

```
class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

    permission_classes = (CustomUpdatePermission,) # specify custom permission class here
    ...
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Tokens to authenticate your users, with DRF you can access the current user in `request.user` as you can see in [Docs](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/).

So, you can match the `request.user`'s with the incoming `id` in url, or use only the `request.user` to update info and stop passing `id` via URL.

Comment: I agree fully, stop passing the user's id altogether

Comment: I could modify it, but on our client side we have a persistence model, the *user* object is mapped `/users/{id}/` and current user is an instance of the object. so for mapping purposes we don't want to use just `/users/` endpoint

Comment: Well, but you can ignore it, and use only `request.user` to update data.

Comment: @Gocht what if admin wants to update particular user info?